# How to Edit Extensible Service Proxy configuration file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I need to integrate OAuth2 in my Project with AppEngine Backend. I am planning to use firebase Auth with AppEngine to take care of security.
Tutorial used : https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/authenticating-users#configuring_extensible_service_proxy_to_support_client_authentication

Where is the Extensible Service Proxy configuration file? and how do we edit it ?

Answer (score 1):

I found this question looking for the same thing. I am using cloud-endpoints v2 and GAE. My backend is in python.

For me, in June 2017, it is in the `[yournameandversion]openapi.json`, not a `yaml` file, but it is included automatically when you follow [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/adding-api-management)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this configuration to `openapi.yaml` (formerly `swagger.yaml`):

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
    version: 1.0.0
    title: "My Endpoints"
host: my-backend-api.YOUR-PROJECT-ID.appspot.com
basePath: "/_ah/api"
schemes:
- "https"
consumes:
- "application/json"
produces:
- "application/json"
paths:
    /testAPI/v1/echo:
        get:
            operationId: TestAPIEcho
            responses:
                200:
                    description: A successful response
                    schema:
                        $ref: "#/definitions/echoMessage"
            parameters:
            - name: message
              in: query
              required: true
              type: string
            x-security:
            - firebase

definitions:
    echoMessage:
        properties:
            message:
                type: "string"

security:
- api_key: []

securityDefinitions:
    firebase:
      flow: "implicit"
      type: "oauth2"
      # Replace YOUR-PROJECT-ID with your project ID
      x-issuer: "https://securetoken.google.com/YOUR-PROJECT-ID"
      x-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
```